# How do I modify the source files of a localhost SimpleHTTPServer from a different device on the network?

Tags: python, localhost, simplehttpserver

I have just started to use `SimpleHTTPServers`, and I was wondering how I can modify the source files from another device that is on the network. I want to keep it as simple as possible (right now I am just CDing a file and then type the `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` to the command line). Please tell me if you know of a way to modify these files from another device on the network. Thanks.

Comment: probably I don't understand your problem but I use `ssh` to login on another device on the local network and I have access to all files on this device.

Comment: Sorry if I did not make it clear, I have a simple http localhost server that I run by writing "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000" in the command line. I was wondering how I could edit (edit meaning change the files on the source device) the files that I put on this server from another device that is on the network.

Comment: if you want to change files using web server then you have to write page which let you download file and later upload it back. Or you have to create page which will display form with text from file and there will be button which will send this text (after editing) back to server which will save it in file. All this need more code in Python - and maybe it will be easier to write it with module/framework `Flask` or `Django`

Comment: With `SimpleHTTPServers` you can only download from server but you can't upload. With `python -m CGIHTTPServer 8000` ([CGIHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html)) you can run server which let you run some scripts on server. You could write script which could upload file and save on server.